# IOS: Text Selection in WKWebView (WKSelectionGranularityCharacter)

Tags: ios, textselection, wkwebview

I've got an app that uses a web view where text can be selected. It's long been an annoyance that you can't select text across a block boundary in UIWebView.  WKWebView seems to fix this with a property on its configuration: [`selectionGranularity`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebViewConfiguration_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/WKWebViewConfiguration/selectionGranularity).  One of the possible values is [`WKSelectionGranularityCharacter`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WebKit/Reference/WKWebViewConfiguration_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/tdef/NS_ENUM_AVAILABLE_IOS):

> Selection endpoints can be placed at any character boundary.

Sounds great! Exactly what I need. Except that when I set that in my web view, I often can no longer select text at all.  What is going on? Is there something else I need to set? Has anyone figured this out?

**Update:** I've figured out the following bugs:

1. When there is more than one WKWebView in an app with `selectionGranularity` set to `WKSelectionGranularityCharacter`, only the most recent one to load can select text. I've filed this as bug 18441138.
2. If there is a click handler attached to an element inside the `body` in the HTML content of a WKWebView whose `selectionGranularity` is set to WKSelectionGranularityCharacter, text selection doesn't work inside that element. I've filed this as bug 18440833.
3. Text selection fails in the WKWebView after you've entered edit mode on a UITextView somewhere else in the app until the WKWebView reloads.  I've filed this as bug 18468405.

Has anyone worked around any of these?

Comment: That is very very interesting, thank you for sharing! I've asked a similar question a while back: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21635637/control-text-selection-behavior-in-ios-mobile-safari-and-or-uiwebview Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Same problem happened when I tried to set the granularity to character. thanks for this.

Comment: Is this problem isn't fixed yet? I can recommend to implement desired selection logic using js.

Comment: There is also this bug http://www.openradar.me/23345435

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These and other issues are all fixed as of iOS 13.

Answer (score 1):

There are several known bugs that are still not fixed.

You can execute JavaScript to get selected text as a workaround.

```
window.getSelection().toString()
```

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getSelection)