# Fast-Tap in UIWebView and WKWebView

Tags: ios, uiwebview, webkit, wkwebview

WebKit's [fast tap](https://webkit.org/blog/5610/more-responsive-tapping-on-ios/) functionality has come to Safari in iOS 9.3 ([see documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/releasenotes/General/WhatsNewInSafari/Articles/Safari_9_1.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014305-CH10-SW1)). I work on an e-reader app that uses a web view to display text. We still use `UIWebView` because of [various](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26046098/wkwebview-and-uimenucontroller) [bugs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25938393/text-selection-in-wkwebview-wkselectiongranularitycharacter) in `WKWebView`, but I can switch out to `WKWebView` very easily for testing purposes. We have our own custom touch handling to get around the 350 ms touch delay so links feel faster. I just tried out the fast-tap thing, and it only appears to work in `WKWebView`. Is this correct / confirmed / documented somewhere? Or should fast-tap work in both `UIWebView` and `WKWebView`?

**Update:** [here](https://dzone.com/articles/300-ms-click-delay-and-ios-8) is an article about some changes toward the current fast-tap behavior in iOS 8 that only appeared in `WKWebView`. But nothing about the new iOS 9.3 stuff.